# Font does't load on from HTTP to HTTPS due to no Access-Control-Allow-Origin header

Tags: https

Access to Font at https://booklu.in/catalog/view/theme/fastor/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.3.0 from origin http://booklu.in has been blocked by CORS policy:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

How do I address this issue?

Comment: If you have SSL, why are you even using http?  But your website seems to have more problems than the CORS issue, it doesn't load fully.  You need to address them.